# How to concatenate strings formatted with sprintf in C

Tags: c, string-concatenation, strcpy, formatted

I have multiple sentences which are being printed in the console currently. I have to gather them into a string.

A part of the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer [100];
    sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", 5, 3, 5+3);
    char *c=buffer;
    sprintf (buffer, "and %d minus %d is %d", 6, 3, 6-3);
    strcat(c, buffer);
    printf ("[%s]",c);
    return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create formatted string using sprintf, but the result is wrong. The length of the sentences and their count are unlimited.

I want the output from the above code to be like:

> [5 plus 3 is 8and 6 minus 3 is 3]

But it is:

> [and 6 minus 3 is 3and 6 minus 3 is 3]

How do I need to concatenate them? Also, the length of the sentences and their count are unlimited. I have difficulties in using malloc and realloc. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the purpose of using a char pointer and assign the buffer array to it, when you can directly print the buffer?

Comment: Assigning the address of an array to a pointer does not copy the contents.

Comment: For the `malloc()` and friends, please post another question. It is an unrelated question.

Comment: When I directly print the buffer without using char pointer, only the string from the last spritnf is stored and printed.

Comment: Use two buffers, concatenate them and print those instead of using a pointer anyway.

Comment: But I have too many sentences which means that I need to declare too many buffers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sprintf (buffer, "and %d minus %d is %d", 6, 3, 6-3);` re-writes `buffer` instead of concatenating. The original result of the previous `sprintf()` is lost.

`strcat(c, buffer);`appends `buffer` to itself.  As that overlaps, it is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Do not do that.

---

Instead use the return value of `sprintf()` (number of characters printed) to determine the offset printing.

```
int offset = sprintf (buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", 5, 3, 5+3);
offset += sprintf (buffer + offset, " and %d minus %d is %d", 6, 3, 6-3);
offset += sprintf (buffer + offset, " even more");
printf ("[%s]",buffer);
```

---

Avoid `strcat()` as that requires code to iterate down the prior string, resulting in [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).  Better to keep track of the string length and use that for the next `sprintf()`.

---

Better code could use `snprintf()` to prevent buffer overrun.

```
// Pedantic example
char buffer [100];
size_t offset = 0;
size_t available = sizeof buffer;

int retval = snprintf (buffer, available, "%d plus %d is %d", 5, 3, 5+3);
if (retval < 0 || (unsigned) retval >= available) Handle_Overflow();
offset += retval;
available -= retval;

retval = snprintf (buffer + offset, available, " and %d minus %d is %d", 6, 3, 6-3);
if (retval < 0 || (unsigned) retval >= available) Handle_Overflow();
offset += retval;
available -= retval;

retval = snprintf (buffer + offset, available, " even more");
if (retval < 0 || (unsigned) retval >= available) Handle_Overflow();
offset += retval;
available -= retval;

printf ("[%s]",buffer);
```

---

> length of the sentences and their count are unlimited.

Usually a large buffer is sufficient as *unlimited* is not really **unlimited**, just potentially large.  C *strings* are limited to `SIZE_MAX`.

Alternative: research non-C standard [`asprintf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html).

Comment: Of course with the admonition to check that `offset` plus the anticipated length of the string literal and conversions doesn't exceed the buffer size (minus 1). (you got it whilst I was pecking away...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True, hence the "Better code could use snprintf()" part of  the answer.  I would have detailed that for OP, yet wanted to address the non-`strcat()` solution first.

Comment: If you are old enough, you will remember a sit-com who's intro used `"Schlemiel"` in two different pronunciations and a reference to "Hasenpfeffer Incorporated" `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [Surely](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074016/) you can't be serious - and [stop calling me Shirley](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM2K7sV-K74). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Good program needs nice design.Simplify it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stdout, "%d plus %d is %d", 5, 3, 5+3);
    fprintf (stdout, "and %d minus %d is %d", 6, 3, 6-3);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to deal with the **unlimited** problem, you can output to a file or other.

Comment: This answer is a bit like telling someone who wants to learn to swim that they should go for a run instead. Learning how to move data around in buffers, and understanding exactly how much and where you're placing data are very valuable skills in C. Sidestepping the issue doesn't do much to teach how to work through this problem.

Comment: Do you think he needs to learn'malloc' or'realloc'  through this question?

Comment: It's certainly an option, not the definitive answer, but it could offer insight on a different way to approach the problem. chux's answer has an example of maintaining bounds and offsets on a stack allocated buffer, perhaps you could show us how to solve this with dynamically allocated memory? Either way, your current answer is an answer to a completely different question (namely, *How do I print interpolated data?*), having nothing to do with string concatenation.